# Cut Copy Paste in new sheet and updates status as "Updated" in new column

Tags: excel, vba

I have data of 2 columns in sheet1 which a macro copies to sheet 2 and remove the same from sheet1! what I want is after macro paste data in sheet2 to there is a 3rd column viz status, this status column should be filed with status "updated".
[image: Sheet1 (POL)]

[image: Sheet2 where the data and macro button is]

So after I run the macro the data is pasted in sheet2 but I also want that status column to be filled automatically as Updated.
Macro copy-pastes the data into sheet2 but does not update the status column!!! Please help....
[image: This is the error I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot test a range of value in the same time in your if statement. That's why you have "Type mismatch".

Please try to use a for statement instead :

```
for i = 2 to 100
    if range("B" & i).value = "FST" then
        range("C" & i).value = "updated"
    end if
next
```